# Exclude a specific directory from SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, url-rewriting

I have the following URL rewrite in htaccess to redirect URLS first to https and secondly to WWW if its not already. using the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index.php/fsukblog/(.*)$ https://www.thisdomain.com/index.php/blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

what I want to do is to exclude index.php/acars from the SSL so it works via http as a 3rd party piece of software connects to scripts within acars and wont work over SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect http to https://www, and to exclude /index.php/acars from https redirection, you can use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} OFF [NC]
RewriteCond www.%{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(www\..+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.php/acars https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for and tidies it up nicely. Thanks very much @starkeen

Comment: if I wanted to add a second url i.e. action.php/fsfk do i just recreate the last line or would it need to be added to the last line in a kind of if/else?